# Identifying Source Date for Visible ESRI World Imagery in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, basemap, arcgis-online-basemaps, identify

Using ArcMap 10.2.2 I want to identify the source data of the Esri Satellite Basemap 'World Imagery'.
When using the identify tool you can select which layer of the World Imagery you want to identify - for example: 'low resolution 15m Imagery', 'high resolution 16 cm Imagery' and these often have different source dates.
How do I know which is the layer that is visible? As they are all layered on top of each other, I cannot use the 'visible layers' function.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any programming prowess?

Comment: @MichaelStimson no unfortunately not

Comment: If you knew some scripting/programming you can use the available object information: Each of the basemap layers has a min and max scale, you can determine the current map scale and make an informed choice which one is active then query the metadata from that. I would suggest that arcpy is very much a part of ArcGIS for users that have a more than casual relationship with GIS in general.

Comment: I'd be happy to give it a try. Can you direct me to what code I should use? Also, where do you see what the min and max scale is for the individual basemap layers?

Comment: It's all in the layer object https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/ there's a bit of code at the bottom. A basemap layer is a group layer (a layer containing layers) so use arcpy.mapping.ListLayers https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000002n000000 on the basemap layer to get its child layers. You can use the ArcMap python window to test your code, then when you get something you like copy/paste into a text file for later use but get rid of the >>> and ... text or you will get syntax errors when you try to reuse it.